# Unknown issue with Google Play services

Tags: android, eclipse, google-drive-api, google-play-services

We are trying to set up the example projects for google drive on our tablet (Hannspad SN14T71BUE). So far we have tried the [quickstart project](https://github.com/googledrive/android-quickstart) and the sample project included with the Google Play services APK.

We have set up Google Play services to the T (http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/drive.html). I set our account to be a registered developer on Google, and I referenced our projects in the developer's console credentials section.

We are developing using Eclipse IDE and cannot use usb debugging as there are no drivers to support our tablet. We are able to export the projects as signed apks and install them fine, but when we start the applications, we get the message "Unknown issue with Google Play services."

We have wiped the tablet and reset it to factory defaults, loaded our google account and added google play services to the tablet again and again, but we still keep getting the same message.

Comment: Does the device actually have Google Play Services?

Answer (score 1):

The Hannspad SN14T71BUE tablet is Android-compatible, but it isn't actually Android.  This means that it doesn't come with GMail, Google Maps, Play Store, or Google Play Services (which is delivered via the Play Store).

Google Play Services is limited to only Android devices.  It sounds like you tried side-loading the service (probably when you got messages along the lines of "Google Play Services is not supported on this device"), but this won't work.